# Using a query in the lookup transform of vega-lite inside Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, vega-lite, vega

I have an index containing two fields which are disjoint. Since I can't fetch both the fields using a union query (Elasticsearch doesn't support union queries yet), I was trying to use Vega-Lite's lookup transform to send a separate query to retrieve the second disjoint field.

```
[{"a": "10", "b": "x"}, {"a": "20", "b": "y"}, {"a": "25", "b": "z"} ....

.... {"a": "21", "c": "l"}, {"a": "22", "c": "m"}, {"a": "40", "c": "n"}]
```

I'd like to get the values for b and c for a's from 20 to 25
The answer in this case would be b = ["y", "z"], c = ["l", "m"]

My vega-lite json config looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": {
      "index": "index-name",
      "query": "" // Query to fetch all values of b
    },
  "transform": [{
    "lookup": "",  // What to put here?
    "from": {
      "data": {
        "url": {
          "index": "index-name",
          "query": "" // Query to fetch all values of c
        }
      },
      "key": "",  // What to put here?
      "fields": []  // and here?
    }
  }],
  "mark": ...,
  "encoding": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Essentially what I'm looking for is obtaining the values of b first and then selecting a range of a's
and querying again over this range of a's for c's.

Is it possible?
Because I keep running into errors in Vega-lite.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in vega-lite editor. You will need 2 data set, 1 is c_data and the other is for b_data. The transform lookup is like a left join, so the join will only work for the 'a' field having common values.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "datasets": {
    "c_data": [
      {"a": "21", "c": "l"},
      {"a": "25", "c": "m"},
      {"a": "40", "c": "n"}
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "name": "b_data",
    "values": [
      {"a": "10", "b": "x"},
      {"a": "20", "b": "y"},
      {"a": "25", "b": "z"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "lookup": "a",
      "from": {"data": {"name": "c_data"}, "key": "a", "fields": ["c"]},
      "as": ["c"]
    }
  ],
  "width": "container",
  "height": "container",
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "encoding": {"x": {"field": "c"}, "y": {"field": "a", "type": "quantitative"}}
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.